# How to implement ion-chip clickable, when click page navigate to another page?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router, ionic4

I am ionic 4 framework, in that i used ion-chip, i want to this ion-chip clickable. for example when i click on ion-chip navigate to another page.[Here is the ion-chip documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/chip)

Comment: post what u have tried

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add routerLink any element to navigate to another page.

```
<ion-chip routerLink="/home">
  <ion-label>Home</ion-label>
</ion-chip>

<ion-chip>
  <ion-label routerLink="/details/42" color="secondary"> Details </ion-label>
</ion-chip>
```

Or you in component (html) :

```
<ion-chip (ionClick)="openPage()">
   <ion-label>Home</ion-label>
</ion-chip>
```

component :

```
openPage(){
   this.router.navigateByUrl('/home');
}
```

Comment: Is it possible passing json object through it? for example in html file: [navPush]="somePage"   [navParams]="{'id': some.id}"

Answer (score 1):

If you add tappable directive on then it also good working

```
<ion-chip (click)="openPage()" tappable>
   <ion-label>Home</ion-label>
</ion-chip>
```

Comment: The classic 300ms delay thankfully hasn’t been an issue in Ionic for a very long time. So, there’s need tappable, at least for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted my ionic desktop users to view the hyperlink in the status bar so these two work as well:

`<ion-chip><a href="https://www.stackoverflow.com/">Test chip</a></ion-chip>`
or
`<a href="https://www.stackoverflow.com/"><ion-chip>Test chip</ion-chip></a>`